# Get Textarea Value with Simpe HTML Dom

Tags: textarea, simple-html-dom, html-parser

i using simple_html_dom.php

how to get textarea value if the website has used bad tag.

the textarea tag already closed before `</textarea>` like input tag.

Textarea HTML like below:

```
<textarea name="xxx" id="xxx" />this is value</textarea>
```

When i use this function, i dont get anything

```
$textarea = $html->find("textarea[name=xxx]"); 
$contents = $textarea->innertext;
echo $contents;
```

how to get 'this is value' using simple_html_dom.php or other alternative?

Thank you

Comment: `find("path", $N)` returns an array of DOM elements OR the Nth element if the index `$N` is specified... So in your case, `$html->find("textarea[name=xxx]", 0);` should work...

Answer (score 1):

Well, my previous comment won't work in this case, I'll leave it for info though...

Another approach is to clean it up before parsing it with simple_html_dom using [`Tidy extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php). But it seems not to be working here either...

A last approach I can think of, and if this is your only problematic case, is to use regex to get what you want:

- Using `<textarea.*?name="xxx".*?id="xxx".*?\/>([^<]+)<\/textarea>` ==> [`RegEx DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/gN1hZ7/1)
- The output will be in group one of the resulting array `$match`. Check this working code:

  ```
  $input =  <<<_DATA_ 
  <textarea name="xxx" id="xxx" />this is value</textarea>
  _DATA_;

  $pattern = '/<textarea.*?name="xxx".*?id="xxx".*?\/>([^<]+)<\/textarea>/';

  preg_match($pattern, $input, $match);
  var_dump($match)
  ```

  [`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eu7k-8nqw)

Comment: good solution, is likely to work perfectly. i have to try this. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the value of a  `Teaxtarea` in javascript:

```
 <script type=text/javascript>

function getValueTextarea()
{
   var vl=document.getElementById("tx").value;
   alert(vl);
}

</script>

<body>
   <textarea id="tx">Value Of Textarea</textarea>
   <input id="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getValueTextarea()">  
</body>
```